# get_host() fails in a for loop

Tags: python, ip

I can get the host of the ip by calling get_host(), but only if I do it for one IP. 
When I put a for loop over it to check a list of IPs, it just fails with an error: 
"Whois lookup failed for 'some.ip'."

Very strange behaviour. Can someone explain why this happens, or what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Assuming you pasted correctly, your indentation is off. The Try/Except block needs to be indented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'79.133.217.242' is the failing IP. I imported into my shell and tried myself. The IP in your non-loop example is not in your list of IP's. Code looks fine, just bad IP

If you ping it, you get a timeout

```
PING 79.133.217.242 (79.133.217.242): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```